# How to create tab like buttons in iPad to switch between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

I want create a `view` with a line of `UIButtons` at the top of the `view`. While user selects each button he/she should be able to switch between the `views`.

I tried it by adding the `view` one above the other in .xib and setting the `view.hidden = NO` and `view.hidden = YES`. But I know this is not the proper way to implement this.

Can you experts please suggest a good way to implement this scenario?

[image: Sample image]

Comment: add that view to window.

Comment: @sunny can you please explain in detail.

Comment: The iOS Human Interface Guidelines labour the point of [embracing iOS UI paradigms](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppDesign/AppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW10). Apple provides a `UITabBar` your users will be accustomed to and Apple supplies [guidelines as to how a tabbed interface should look/work](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1). Just bringing it to your attention.

Comment: are you getting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITabBar. But this will not give you two lines of tabs, I guess. If you are satisfied with one line of tab and other tab will be hidden like the old iPod application in iPhone, then UITabBar is an option.